# CLI network management

Tags: command-line, wifi, networkmanager

I've set up a console typewriter: a laptop with a minimal Debian install and no X server. I use it as a typewriter and I use wifi to sync my documents.

I connect to wifi using wpa-supplicant. That involves editing /etc/network/interfaces each time I connect to a new network - and that a little tiresome.

What would be a good CLI network manager that could make connecting to new networks easier. It should be able to:

- Shows a list of available networks
- Let me select one and connect by time the WPA password
- Remembers passwords and automatically connect to the connections that I've used before

Comment: There is `wpa-cli` which is packaged with `wpa-supplicant`. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant.

Comment: I second that. Add netctl and wifi-menu and you have automated discovery and a curses interface. Try any arch live install disk and connecting is as simple as typing wifi-menu on the command line, typing a password, and waiting 15 seconds. Alternatively wicd is pretty simply managed as well.